# Round corners of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to round the corners of a `UITableViewController` or even the entire `UINavigationController` using the following code:

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
```

The problem though is that when the view is rounded off, the `UINavigationBar` has a translucent, frosty background showing outside the rounded edges. I want to keep the navigation bar translucent, but I want the entire view to be rounded. With the code above, I get the following result:

[image]

How can I produce this result without the frosty background showing outside the rounded corners?

Comment: Set the window background color same as navigation bar color

Comment: Set self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: @PradhyumanSinhChavda It doesn't change anything.

Comment: I wonted if you set all the following sugestions to the correct view. You may try to do that to the superview e.g. `self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

//edit//
actually, because its the nav bar there you probably want

```
self.navigationController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
self.navigationController.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

///

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add this two KeyPath in the view in which you need round corners

Comment: Same results. Didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line of code :

```
[self.tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.tableView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
 self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
 self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 self.tableView.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
 self.tableView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
 self.tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
 self.tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

Comment: Still nothing changed. :\

Comment: create subview and table insert into subview. and round corner in subview i am fatch same issue some days ago. :)