# iOS - Rounded rectangle around text in UITableViewCell like Things app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have searched high and low, trying to work out how to achieve the effect seen both in the iOS settings app and Things for iPhone (an app by CulturedCode seen below).

In iOS Settings, when there is an OS update available, the cell shows a 1 in the cell to the very right, but the number is surrounded by a rounded rectangle which is dark grey.

The Things for iPhone app has similar in the following screenshot in the Inbox cell:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect in iOS 8 using Swift 1.2?

Comment: Create custom UIView.

Comment: You can achieve round corners from Storyboard/XIB itself. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26251553/2223492) out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a label. Set the font. Set the text color to white:

```
numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Set the background color:

```
numberLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Set the cornerRadius:

```
numberLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Clip to bounds:

```
numberLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked a charm! I thought it might be a more standard thing seeing that it was in the iOS Settings app, but that works just as easily too!

Comment: I haven't seen another way to do this, except using a custom view. After doing this 10 times or so you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer:

[objective C Rounded corners in a UITableView (*iOS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049226/rounded-corners-in-a-uitableview-ios7)

Similar code should work for Swift 1.2 on your UITableViewCell:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UILabel for this, adjusting properties on its layer (A `CALayer` instance which does the actual drawing of the label)

```
let badge = UILabel()
// Give the badge some content and size, then:
badge.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
badge.layer.cornerRadius = badge.bounds.size.height * 0.5
```

I've used this approach many times in the past. Instead of creating the label in code, you can also use this approach with a label that's loaded from a xib or storyboard just as well.